# MVC auto generated create page with a date throws non-null item required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a simple table with a non-nullable date field. The field has a default value of GetDate() in the DB. 
The DB table is brought forward via EntityFramework,
When I let the MVC 4 templates auto-generate a create.cshtml page for that table it works but when I try to run that table I get the error:
**The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'.**

CSHTML file:

```
@model MyModel.Content
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ActiveDate)
    </div>      
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ActiveDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ActiveDate)
    </div>
```

The EF auto-generated class:

```
public partial class Content
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Content1 { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ActiveDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DeactiveDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastEditDate { get; set; }
    public string LastEditor { get; set; }

    public virtual ContentCategory ContentCategory { get; set; }
}
```

This doesn't seem like that unusual of a way to do this. Shouldn't the templates be able to deal with creating a new non-nullable date?

What must I do to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I deal with this is to use nullable DateTimes on my viewmodel and set the [Required] attribute on them, so that if the model validates, then I can guarantee when I copy the values to my entity model and save the data, then it will succeed.  This way you can keep your entity model(what is saved to the database) as a non-null datetime.

The other option is to provide a default value for the datetime if there is something sensible, based on other data or based on current datetime.  For example, defaulting ActiveDate to the current date, so that by default it begins to be active now.

Otherwise the first option is the best, because you don't want to provide a nonsensical default like 1/1/0001

Comment: So you are creating a view model and then using that as opposed to the autogenerated model and CSHTML files? I could do that but I am trying to see how far the auto-generated files can take me.

Comment: @JohnS Begin by copying the model class and tweaking the view model class from there.  Therefore, in this case your view should work with just a change to the `@model` at the top to point to the viewmodel, since all the field names will be the same name/type.